# Deploy custom workflow developed in jbpm into alfresco

Tags: deployment, workflow, alfresco

I am using alfresco 3.0 .. I followed the link below to install jbpm and start creating jbpm workflow ..

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration

In the link It says there are 2 ways of deploying .. first one through designer deploy tab and the other is manually..

I could make it work trough deploy tab.

can anyone tell how can deploy manually .. as the info in the link is insufficient..

I want to know how does it work.. like where i need to place the deployer bean .. ect

Thanks

Comment: Alfresco 3.0? That's quite old... You probably want to upgrade, there have been loads of bugs fixed since then!

Comment: Take a good look at workflow console. It is really handy during development: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_Console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two links that tell you where to put things:

- first and foremost, [Packaging And Deploying Extensions](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Packaging_And_Deploying_Extensions) describe how and where to create your custom Spring configuration files, among other things
- then [Workflow Administration](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration#Manually_deploying_a_jPDL_XML_file_or_Process_Archive) describe workflow specific configuration tasks

An old but mostly still valid [article](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-workflow/advanced-workflow-article.pdf) from [Jeff Potts](http://ecmarchitect.com/) might also come in handy for you.

Answer (score 2):

The first way about I know is to write bean in context file (it will be deployed while alfresco starts)- can looks like that (in  *`\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension`*)

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>

    <beans>                                              
       <!-- custom Workflow bean -->
       <bean id="WorkflowID" parent="workflowDeployer">
          <property name="workflowDefinitions">
             <list>
                <props>
                   <prop key="engineId">activiti</prop>
                   <prop key="location">alfresco/extension/nameOfTheFile.bpmn</prop>
                   <prop key="mimetype">text/xml</prop>
                   <prop key="redeploy">true</prop>
                </props>
             </list>
          </property>
       </bean>

<!-- custom model BEAN -->
       <bean id="SomeID2.dictionaryBootstrap" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
            <property name="models">
                <list>
                    <value>alfresco/extension/Somename-model.xml</value>
                </list> 
            </property>
       </bean>    

    </beans>
```

And the second way how to deploy is workflow console
URLs, eg.:

- Alf 4.2.f *`/alfresco/faces/jsp/admin/workflow-console.jsp`*
- Alf 5.0.d *`/alfresco/s/admin/admin-workflowconsole`*

(write help for the help)

For deploy:
activiti - eg. *`deploy activiti alfresco/extension/wfFileName.bpmn`*
jbpm - eg. *`deploy jbpm alfresco/extension/wfFileName.bpmn`*

gl

**EDIT: 
That's for activiti, not sure if it could be the same :)**

Btw there should be also way how to deploy through "data dictionary" :)